# Maven error :"Updating Maven Project"

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I have installed Eclipse 32 bits  EE with Maven and Spring but when I create new project with Maven, I keep getting the following error message :

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
loader constraint violation: loader 
(instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) 
previously initiated loading for a different type with name 
"org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject"
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: what do you mean by maden? maven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a [known problem](https://jira.spring.io/browse/STS-3443) in some version combinations of Spring-Eclipse integration.

Upgrade or downgrade.

Comment: Known problem link is not live

Comment: @IndrajeetGour fixed, though this was 2013, so things might've changed since then...

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error.  I had installed m2e using "Install New Software" in Eclipse Java EE Kepler.  I eventually found out that Eclipse Java EE Kepler already had a whole bunch of stuff installed already including m2e.  I deleted Eclipse and then re-extracted it and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Close the eclipse and try to run eclipse with clean flag

> eclipse -clean

And now try to create or update any maven project.