# Converting the maven project shows error

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

When I try to change the Dynamic web project into Maven project it shows the error:

[image: screenshot for your reference]

Please anyone share your suggestion.

Comment: Please add the error as text as currently it is unreadable...

Comment: This [link will](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401684/maven-error-updating-maven-project) help u